# How to align content in div to other div contents in horizontal flex?

Tags: css

I have couple of Card divs in `display: flex, direction: row`.
Each card has a title and body.
If title is large, body starts further below;
if title is small, body starts at line 2.

How to ensure that body starts at same line, no matter the size of title.

Expected:
[image]

Got:
[image]

Comment: if you don't want to go in a perhaps too heavy javascript solution (counting character numbers, size, regarding box width... not so complicated but some lines of code), perhaps the easiest would be to always put an height of 2 lines in title (2em, in fact certainly 3 em)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming bottom of the box is in always same height.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 1 33.3333%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.holder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here. Lorem ipsum text goes here.</p>
    <div class="holder">
      <h2>5000</h2>
      <h3>Another stuff here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here.</p>
    <div class="holder">
      <h2>5000</h2>
      <h3>Another stuff here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum text goes here.</p>
    <div class="holder">
      <h2>5000</h2>
      <h3>Another stuff here</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```